# How to cancel a previously called method when a new instance of that method is called

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellation, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

I have an async method `Foo` that gets called at various points in the execution of my code, based on events coming in. I need a way to cancel any thread/instance of this method that is running whenever a new instance is called, effectively "refreshing" the method.

I thought about having a cancellationTokenSource as a class variable.
I tried the following:

```cs
public static MyClass 
{
  static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

  public static async Task<Object> foo()
  {
    Object out = null;
    var previousTokenSource = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cancellationTokenSource, new CancellationTokenSource());
    CancellationToken currentToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    try
    {
      previousTokenSource?.Cancel();

      await Task.Delay(1000, currentToken);
      out = ArbitraryLogic(currentToken)
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
      return null;
    }

    return out;
  }
}
```

So if I have the test function:

```cs
public async void Test()
{
    var out1 = MyClass.foo();
    await Task.Delay(10);
    var out2 = MyClass.foo();

    await out1;
    await out2;
    if (out1.Result != null)
        Assert.Fail("out1.Result not null");
}
```

I expect `out1` to be null, but currently it's not. What am I doing wrong? How would I write code that effectively stops the execution of a method when a new one is called?

Comment: does `ArbitraryLogic` support cancellation? cancellation is cooperative - it needs support from target code in order to function; also: prefer `OperationCanceledException`

Comment: side note: there is probably a race condition here where; I *think* you should do: `var newSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); var previousTokenSource = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cancellationTokenSource, newSource );` and use `newSource.Token` for cancellation

Comment: TBH was not able to reproduce in ordinary console app. What testing framework do you use? Also note that in theory `CancellationToken currentToken =_cancellationTokenSource.Token` can be a token set by some other invocation, not the current one.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think you should add this comment to the answer.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SPybDS).

Comment: additional additional: `async void` is a huge red flag - that might be why people aren't able to reproduce it - it **must** be `async Task`

Comment: Indeed; it would definitely help if the code in the question actually compiled.

Comment: As a side-note, catching an exception and `return null;` inside the `catch` is cringe. The try/catch block is not important for the question that you are asking, so I would suggest to edit the question and remove it. No need to advertise to your future employers that you are "that kind" of programmer, who has the habit of swallowing the exceptions of a program.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That catch is for detecting `TaskCanceledException` only.  How would you recommend that you detect that `Task.Delay()` was cancelled?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would let the caller of the `foo` to handle the `OperationCancelledException`. If the caller has to know whether the operation was cancelled or not, the best way to know it is to expect the exception and handle it. Cancellation in .NET is communicated through exceptions since the cancellation concept was invented. It's too late to change it now. But if you could, would you change it? And in which way?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think the OP has designed the interface so that `foo()` returns `null` if the operation was cancelled, which seems OK to me, but you'd need to full context and expected usage to really know for sure if that's a good approach.

Comment: @MatthewWatson communicating cancellation by returning `null` is atypical to say the least (in the .NET world). If you are OK with this, I guess you are OK with communicating any kind of exception in general, by [returning a special value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674317/exceptions-vs-special-return-values) that the caller of the method has to check for?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether the *task* is `null`; you should be asking whether the *result* is `null`:

```
var x = await out1;
var y = await out2;
Assert.IsNull(x); // fine
Assert.IsNotNull(y); // (depends on ArbitraryLogic)
```